# Proper way to backup and restore my python installation

Tags: windows, backup, python

I am about to re-install my WinXP. I have Python 2.7.2 installed on it with many standard and third party libraries. I would like to back up the c:/python27 directory before reinstalling the OS, install fresh python and then copy the contents of the backed up directory into the newly created one. Is this a valid approach? Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a valid approach.  Windows lacks a package manager for things like python.  One thing to remember is that when you use the msi installer, it modifies the system path and filename associations for you, so you may want to consider backing up the directory, then doing a fresh base python install.  Once that is done, you should be able to copy the contents of the old c:\python27 to the new one.